# Inserting into a Trie in C++

Tags: c++

I am doing another project for school that implements a concordance with a Trie abstract data type. I have everything working, except for the insert function. I'm having a little trouble with that.

Sometimes when I try to insert something, it doesn't get inserted. Other times, it produces a segmentation fault. I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong, since most of the code for the insert function came from my professor. I know the operations for the stack are correct, since that came from an earlier project.

Note: We were told to use the end marker to hold the number of times the word appears in the concordance.

Thanks in advance!

**concordance.h**

```
#ifndef CONCORDANCE_H
#define CONCORDANCE_H
#include "stack.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

const int MAX = 8;      // Maximum length of word

class Concordance
{
    public:
        typedef char Item[MAX+1];

        // Constructor
        Concordance() { root = NULL; }

        // Destructor
        ~Concordance();

        // Modification Member Functions
        void insert(Item entry);

        // Constant Member Functions
        int length();
        void print(std::ostream& out_s);

    private:
        // Data Members
        struct Node
        {
            int end_marker;
            Node *children[26];
        };
        Node *root;

        void help_insert(Node* &r, Item w, int pos);
        int find_size(Node *r);
        void help_print(std::ostream& out_s, Node *r, Stack &s);
        void destroy(Node *r);
};
#endif
```

**concordance.cpp**

```
#include "concordance.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

// Destroy function and destructor
void Concordance::destroy(Node *r)
{
    if(r != NULL)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
            destroy(r -> children[i]);
        delete r;
    }
}

Concordance::~Concordance()
{
    destroy(root);
}



// Functions to insert into the tree
void Concordance::help_insert(Node* &r, Item w, int pos)
{
    if (r == NULL)
    {
        r = new Node;
        r -> end_marker = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
            r -> children[i] = NULL;
    }
    if (w[pos] == '\0' && r -> end_marker > 0)
        r -> end_marker = r -> end_marker + 1;
    else if (w[pos] == '\0' && r -> end_marker == 0)
        r -> end_marker = 1;
    else
        help_insert (r -> children[w[pos] - 'a'], w, pos + 1);
}

void Concordance::insert(Item entry)
{
    help_insert(root, entry, 0);
}



// Functions to count the number of words in the tree
int Concordance::find_size(Node *r)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (r == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (r -> end_marker > 0)
        count = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
        count += find_size(r -> children[i]);
    return count;
}

int Concordance::length()
{
    return find_size(root);
}



// Functions to print the tree to an output stream
void Concordance::print(ostream& out_s)
{
    Stack s;
    help_print(out_s, root, s);
}

void Concordance::help_print(ostream& out_s, Node *r, Stack &s)
{
    if (r != NULL)
    {
        if (r -> end_marker > 0)
            s.st_print(out_s);
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
        {
            s.push(i + 'a');
            help_print(out_s, r -> children[i], s);
            s.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Program**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "concordance.h"
using namespace std;

typedef char Word[MAX+1];

void read_word(ifstream& infile, Word array)
{
    char ch;
    int i = 0;

    infile.get(ch);

    while(!infile.eof() && isalpha(ch) && !isspace(ch) && !ispunct(ch))
    { 
        if(i > MAX-1)
        {
            while(!isspace(ch) && !ispunct(ch))
                infile.get(ch);
            break;
        }

        ch = toupper(ch);

        array[i] = ch;
        i++;
        infile.get(ch);
    }
    if(i != 0)
        array[i] = '\0';    // Null Character
}

void make_list(ifstream& infile, Word& array)
{
    Concordance concord;
    int count = 1;
    int length;

    read_word(infile, array);               // Read a word
    while(!infile.eof())                    // While the file isn't empty...
    {
        concord.insert(array);              // Insert into concordance
        read_word(infile, array);           // Read another word
    }

    concord.print(cout);
    length = concord.length();

    cout << "The file contains " << length << " distinct words." << endl;
}

int main()
{
    char file_name[100];
    typedef char Word[MAX+1];
    ifstream infile;
    Word array;

    cout << "Enter a file name: ";
    cin >> file_name;               // Get file name

    infile.open(file_name);         // Open file
    if(!infile)                     // If we couldn't open the file...
    {
        cout << "Failed to open file." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    make_list(infile, array);       // Make the concordance

    infile.close();                 // Close the input file

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's at least one `get(ch)` in there that doesn't have a check for `eof()` afterward.  Also, having the same `typedef` for `Word` both inside and outside `main` seems like a bad idea.  Probably harmless, but you really don't need the one in `main`.

Comment: Also, why are you using `toupper()`, but then treating characters as lowercase here?  `children[w[pos] - 'a']`.  I think you want `'A'` there, not `'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code moves from parent to child, assuming the next character is *lower case*:

```
    help_insert (r -> children[w[pos] - 'a'], w, pos + 1);
```

However, you convert your entire input string to *upper case* here:

```
    ch = toupper(ch);
```

Either modify the trie code to expect upper-case, or modify your code to pass in strings in lower case.  The two alphabets are 32 positions apart in ASCII, and so you're indexing beyond the end of the `children` array in the trie nodes.

Comment: Good call! That is fixed, but I am still having the same issue. Sometimes I am getting a segmentation fault, and sometimes the word isn't being inserted. I'm thinking it has to do with insert().

Comment: This part has me scratching my head a little: `if(i != 0) array[i] = '\0';`  What happens when `read_word` didn't actually read a word?

Comment: For example, if you have two spaces in a row, or, say "word. word" (ie. punctuation followed by a space), I think your word-reading logic will return an empty word.  But because it doesn't manipulate `array`, will it look like you just returned the previous word?  I think you need to rethink your word-reading logic.